# Displaying the Cubemap using GLSL

Tags: opengl, background, glsl, shader

I am currently using a cubemap to display the reflection on a sphere.

The reflection and distortion itself works just fine, but how do I display the cubemap itself like on this image? 
http://evasion.imag.fr/Enseignement/cours/2012/SIA/Shaders/Images/refraction.png

So the sphere is displayed, but I can't seem to figure out how to display the background of my 'cube room' ?

Comment: As far as I can tell the cubemap is already rendered onto the sphere just fine. After all you're already seeing the reflection on it, which *is* the cubemap.

Comment: ok, but I want to display the background as well, just to make it look like on the picture.. how could I do that?

Comment: you need to use a skybox

Comment: Well, how exactly did you draw the sphere? The principle is the same, you need a direction vector from your eye point to the far plane. Once you have this, you can sample from the cube map. If you stay in window-space, then the direction is always going to be in the +Z face of the cube map no matter how the camera is oriented - you probably want to transform into object- or world-space instead.

Answer (score 0):

draw cube/sphere/cylinder centered on camera position and use normals as 3d texture coord while cubemap is binded. your cube... must be big enough to cover whole scene ...